# What about a Distro dedicated to engineers?

Tags: application-development, distro-recommendation

I am Raihan Ali. I am an civil engineering student. I am looking for a distro dedicated to engineers. I want a distro fully loaded with engineering tools. Is there any distro like this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I think this question is best suited at [unix.se]; we are specific to Ubuntu and derivatives, but they can help with other distros. But anyways, from my 2-minute search right, I've found that **CAELinux** seems pretty popular for computer-aided engineering; not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it really does not make sense to me something like "fully loaded with engineering tools".

I know engineers that use Matlab, some else that use CAD, some else Mathematica, some does pretty good sound engineering, someone use Windows, someone use Macs.

Someone other, thought, have everything they need inside the standard Ubuntu, which is a text editor and a compiler.

If you can be more specific on what your needing is, well, maybe there is something for you out there, but your question, as it is, does not really allow for a serious answer ;)